# How do I exit command in Tkinter, Python?

Tags: python, button, tkinter

I want a my programme to display words from list1 and the user will write its translation into the entry. If it's correct or wrong will display on the output label. But when I click on the button nothing happens. I want it to display the next word after clicking, but it doesn't. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks :)

```
def programme(self, frame, list2, list1):
        self.number= 1
        def correct(event):
            if(self.enter_button.cget("text") == "Enter"):
                answer= self.entry.get()
                if(answer.lower() == correct.lower()):
                    self.output.config(text = "Correct!")
                    self.enter_button.config(text = "Next")     
                else:
                    self.output.config(text = "Nope, sorry!", foreground = "red")
                    self.enter_button.config(text = "Next")
            else:
                self.number= self.number+ 1   
                #correct.quit()


        text = list1[self.number]
        correct = list2[self.number]

        self.label = ttk.Label(frame, text = text)
        self.label.grid(row=1, ipady = 5, pady=5)
        self.entry = ttk.Entry(frame)
        self.entry.grid(row=2, sticky="NSWE")
        self.enter_button = ttk.Button(frame, text = "Enter")
        self.enter_button.bind("<Button>", correct)
        self.enter_button.grid(row=3)
        self.output= ttk.Label(frame, text = "",foreground = "black", font = 30, borderwidth=2,  width = 35, anchor="center")
        self.output.grid(row=4, pady = 20)
```

I'm not sure about the correct.quit()

Comment: You have a function and a variable named `correct`.  The variable will override the function.  Rename one of them.

Comment: you assign `.bind("<Button>", list2[self.number])` because you set `correct = list2[self.number]`

Comment: renaming doesn't help. Still doesn't work

Comment: What does "_Still doesn't work_" mean?  I used your code with `correct()` function renamed to `check_answer()` (of course changed the callback name in `bind(...)` as well), then `check_answer()` is executed when `self.enter_button` is clicked.

Comment: I'm sorry. I made a typo. It works now. And thank you ^^

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a "command" argument in the ttk.Button function, like so:
`ttk.Button(background, text="Submit", command=gui.stream)`

That command keyword argument references a function, so in your example `command=programme`

Comment: Isn't that the same as ' self.enter_button.bind("<Button>", correct)' ?

Comment: You probably saw `frame.bind("<Button-1>", callback)` somewhere, which refers to clicking mouse1. That's not the same at all

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know what you mean, then

Comment: `progamme` is the function creating the form.  Assign it to the `command` option of a button in the form will recreate the form when the button is clicked.  Is it what you want to propose?

Comment: Well I guess it's the `def correct()` I want to call. Because first I want to know, if the answer is correct or not. Renaming the variable correct doesn't help.
You mean I should have the `command = programme` as well as `.bind("<Button>", correct)`?
If so, what should I put inside the brackets in `command = programme()`?